# Library installation failed for library due to user error for whl

Tags: databricks

I am trying to install libraries on job clusters at runtime using the libraries API. I am getting the below error.

```
Run result unavailable: job failed with error message
Library installation failed for library due to user error for whl: "abfss://fs-abc-@prod.dfs.core.windows.net/code/abc.whl"
. Error messages:
Library installation attempted on the driver node of cluster 0909-074843-vgsnj1u5 and failed. 
Please refer to the following error message to fix the library or contact Databricks support. 
Error Code: DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. Error Message: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid 
configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

Comment: Well, ever found a solution? Having the same issue.